# Microsoft.SqlServer.SMO included in app

Tags: c#, smo

I am currently writing a backup application in c# using the Microsoft.SqlServer.SMO components and running into some issue getting the application to launch / run on anything other than my dev machine. I am using the ones included with SQL Server 2012 and have the references added and set to copy local. The problem is we use SQL Server 2005, 2008 R2 and 2012 on Windows 2000, Server 2003, Server 2008 R2 and Server 2012. I have also tried using an installer to register the .dlls that are required still not luck any ideas on how to get my app to run correctly on all of the platforms?

Comment: SQL 2012 requires framework 3.5, which doesn't work on Win2K: probably its SMO libs target 3.5 too, so they won't work either.

Comment: But it should work on the other Server 2003 and up correct?

Answer (score 0):

I found out what happened I had built and installer and that messed up the code if so it is working now no worries